# Is this a typo, or am I missing something?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, hyperbolic-functions

I have a handout for my precalc II class.  It says $\sinh(-x) = -\sin(x)$
It should be $\sinh(-x) = -\sinh(x)$ right?  I don't see how a negative input could make a hyperbolic function circular.

Comment: Seems like a typo.

Comment: For questions like this, try wolframalpha: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=does+sinh%28-x%29+%3D+-sin%28x%29

Also Wolfram alpha shows 'true' for $\sinh(-x) = -\sinh(x)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The handout is in error. It should say $$\sinh(-x)=-\sinh x$$ as you suggest.

You may be interested to know that there *is* a relationship between circular and hyperbolic functions. It is true that $$\sin( \pm ix )= \pm i\sinh x.$$ You may find it fun to determine all of the similar relationship using the other functions ($\cos$ with $\cosh$, *etc.*).

Moreover, this formula (and friends) can be used with the familiar sum formula to immediately give cool formulas like $$\sin(x\pm iy)=\sin x \cosh y \pm i\cos x \sinh y.$$

Answer (score 2):

Now $\sinh x:=\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}$ by definition.

Hence
$\sinh(-x)=\frac{e^{-x}-e^{x}}{2}=-\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}=-\sinh x$.

So you're right: a negative input doesn't change the hyperbolic nature of the function. But if you work with complex numbers things begin to be more intriguing and such a case could happen, for example if $z\in\mathbb C$ you have $\sinh z=-i\sin(iz)$. See the related Wikipedia page.